# How to get ElasticSearch DSL from a SearchRequest object in Java？

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I build a query request by SearchRequestBuilder.

But now I want to get the equivalent json type DSL.

It is possible to get it from a SearchRequestBuilder or SearchRequest object?

My ElasticSearch Version : 8.2.0

It seems that there is no any way to get it from the SearchRequest object.

I found another combersome way: Use wireshark/tshark to capture the http package and then the dsl json is in the body.

Comment: Just making sure : you are using the new client (that replaces the previous High Level Rest Client) ?

Comment: I am sure.  The search method in the new client can recieve a lambda function or SearchRequest object. Because the search request is so complicated that I choose to pass a SearchRequest object to it. But I found no way to generate the DSL by it.  @GPI

Comment: Someone tell me to use a thirdparty library bboss.